# Short syntax for OUTER JOIN with one different column in the SELECT list

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

In my Postgres database, I would like to join table A and table B to get table C. Table B is treated like an overlay over table A:

Table A: "new"

| id | new | operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | newval1 | INSERT |
| 2 | newval2 | UPDATE |

Table B "old"

| id | old | operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | oldval2 | UPDATE |
| 3 | oldval3 | DELETE |

Table C "joined"

| id | new | old | operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | newval1 | NULL | INSERT |
| 2 | newval2 | oldval2 | UPDATE |
| 3 | NULL | oldval3 | DELETE |

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(n.id, o.id), n.new, o.old, 
    COALESCE(n.operation, o.operation) 
FROM
    "new" n 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    old o ON n.id = o.id
```

I am looking for shorter syntax. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What is wrong with your full outer join approach?

Comment: I hate the coalesce part in reality I have a lot of columns

Comment: "...I hate the coalesce part in reality I have a lot of columns..." - You are out of luck. That's how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do *something* with the `USING` clause:

```sql
SELECT id                                               -- this is simpler now
     , n.new, o.old, 
     , COALESCE(n.operation, o.operation) AS operation  -- but not this
FROM   new n 
FULL   OUTER JOIN old o USING (id);                     -- !
```

Columns listed in the `USING` clause are only included in the output *once*, so an unqualified `id` in the `SELECT` list effectively replaces `COALESCE(n.id, o.id) AS id`.

Care must be taken when joining  more tables: column names on the left must be unambiguous.
And the unqualified reference in the `SELECT` list is only possible if the same column name isn't added in another table to the right.
This makes the `USING` clause more susceptible to breakage when altering a query later. So use it carefully.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.2)

> ... the output of `JOIN USING` suppresses redundant columns: there is
> no need to print both of the matched columns, since they must have
> equal values. While `JOIN ON` produces all columns from ***`T1`***
> followed by all columns from ***`T2`***, `JOIN USING` produces one
> output column for each of the listed column pairs (in the listed
> order), followed by any remaining columns from ***`T1`***, followed by
> any remaining columns from ***`T2`***.

But you still need `COALESCE` for other columns.
And you need a column alias for those (missing in your example).